# Must a colon be appended to "that is"?

Tags: punctuation

In certain sentences, I use *that is* to rephrase something, be more specific or elaborate.

Example:

> This coffee is so black, it must have
>   been prepared by someone who works a
>   lot, that is: an insomniac.

But in certain circumstances, this colon is unpractical because there's another colon around. Or it makes the sentence insist too much on this particular point.

And I think that I already saw *that is* without a colon.

Is this punctuation sign required?

Comment: I guess one could write: ‘[…] someone who works a lot, that is, an insomniac.’ However, writing it without a colon or a comma seems strange and wrong — at least to me. Also, I think a comma is more natural than a colon.

Comment: The comma is nice, thanks! It's lighter and may well resolve the emphasis problem that I mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anecdotally, I have only rarely seen people put a colon in that position. The colon implies a certain logical relationship between the clauses, namely that the second clause is an illustration or defining example of the first clause.

A comma is more common.  It is a textual analog of a brief pause in speech.  Since a pause in speech can be used for any one of many purposes -- for opening a new thought, for indicating the speaker's uncertainty, for dramatic effect -- it cannot carry quite the same weight of logic as the more specialized colon.

I can see either being used with "that is", but the comma seems more generic, and thus safer.

Comment: I think that the comma is what I was searching for, thank you. But you don't mention whether punctuation is required at all. I am pretty sure that I saw it without any punctuation. Is this necessarily a mistake? (my "insomniac" example is maybe not adapted to illustrate this, because it talks about a person, and it doesn't play well with "that").

Comment: There are grammatical constructions using "that is" which do not have any punctuation after it.  For example, Shakespeare often wrote things like `The cock, that is the trumpet to the morn,` (Hamlet, I.i.173) which lack any punctuation after the "is". So you could say something like "The cat, that is Felix, caught a mouse". Saying "The cat that is Felix caught a mouse" without any punctuation anywhere would sound odd though. More declarative than exemplary. But I don't think there's a hard or fast rule on this one.

Comment: Thank you, my question seems fully answered now. I know the possibilities and will use them according to the context and my inspiration :) I will wait a bit before accepting your answer, to see if others have something else to say about this.

Answer (score 3):

How about trying

> This coffee is so black, it must have been prepared by someone who works a lot; that is, an insomniac.

It clarifies your point without insisting too much.

Comment: I think that I understand you point. By splitting the sentence with a semicolon, the ending doesn't look too much like a conclusion, which was indeed the problem. That said, my example isn't perfect. One big problem that I had, and that I didn't illustrate, is when the "that is" construct appears in the middle of the sentence. In such cases, I don't want to break the rhythm, "that is" is only meant to precise a detail. This is also what I tried to say about insisting too much. In these cases a colon would split the sentence at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the colon implies the introductory phrase "that is,"which clarifies or emphasizes the independent/complete clause that precedes the colon. The phrase that follows the colon (which can be a dependent or independent clause)is often in the form of a list or appositive. For the given example,try this:
This coffee is so black, it must have been prepared by someone who works a lot: an insomniac.
This way (in which the dependent clause following the colon is an appositive) there is the implication of the phrase "that is," in the connection between "someone who works a lot" and "an insomniac."

Here is another example:

Punctuation is fascinating only to those who have no other lives: English teachers.